# Passing function as parameter and calling it javascript

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I ran into an example of javascript code as below and am not clear on how it works. I am used to passing functions as callbacks, but I cannot seem to grasp how

1. the variable func could take arguments (a, b), and
2. why the function pair would be called in that fashion.

```js
function cons(a, b) {
    const pair = func => {
        return func(a, b);
    };
    return pair;
}

function car(pair) {
    return pair((a, b) => {
        return a;
    });
}

function cdr(pair) {
    return pair((a, b) => {
        return b;
    });
}

console.log(cons(1, 2))
//  ƒ pair(func) {return func(a, b);}
console.log(car(cons(1, 2)))
// 1
console.log(cdr(cons(1, 2)))
// 2
```

Comment: (1) is because [`pair` is a closure over `a` and `b`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). I don't understand (2).

Comment: seems to be a copy of TRUE, FALSE and IFELSE methods from lambda calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `func` takes arguments `a` and `b` because they're parameters in the `cons` function. The function call occurs like that (I believe you're talking about a function being logged to the console) because `cons` returns a function, which you don't call - therefore, you pass more arguments (callback functions) like so:

```js
function cons(a, b) {
    const pair = func => {
        return func(a, b);
    };
    return pair;
}

function car(pair) {
    return pair((a, b) => {
        return a;
    });
}

function cdr(pair) {
    return pair((a, b) => {
        return b;
    });
}

cons(1, 2)(console.log);
console.log(car(cons(1, 2)))
// 1
console.log(cdr(cons(1, 2)))
// 2
```

Comment: Okay. On 1, I'm not used to passing arguments to anything that isn't defined like func(a, b), but it's good to know I can. On 2, I see... I'm just passing a callback with arguments a and b, and returns a or b as func.  Makes sense now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

in simple words, it's all happening because of `closure`! you are calling a function `cons` which internally returns another function definition which internally refers the properties `a` and `b` which are in the scope of `cons` [ a parent ] function.

to add more lights, let's do some simple changes and you can see it,

```js
function cons(a, b) {
    const pair = func => {
        console.log('a: ', a);
        console.log('b: ', b);
    };
    return pair;
}

let childFun = cons(10, 30);
console.log(childFun());
```

now, `cons` returns some function which accepts one function as a parameter and executes that function on remembered `a` and `b`. in next, you are passing that closure function `car` function and `car` function is triggering that function by passing another callback which accepts both `a` and `b` but returns just `b`.

and in the same way, `cdr` function does with `b`